# Django serving wrong template at the wrong address with malformed urls.py (redactor app)

Tags: python, html, django

I’ve got a small experimental Django project which accepts a user’s fake Chuckee Cheese membership card number on the landing page, redacts the first 8 digits and shows it back to the user in redacted form.

Here is my website’s landing page showing `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4cgQ.jpg

When a web user enters their 12 digit card number (for example) ‘111111111111’ into the entry box and clicks the “Redact!” button, Django takes the user to  the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/` location. The redacted card number is present, as expected (below the green  font elements): https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiZen.jpg

The problem there is that the rest of the content is missing. The redaction functionality works but my intention is for Django to re-serve the same landing page with the redacted card number (rather than taking the user to a separate page). The problem now is either with my app’s views.py, urls.py and template (copied below). I’ve been going back and forth swapping out some variables and replacing them with others but I can’t get it to work.

Here is my **urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
   path('home', views.home, name='home'),
   # path('results', views.results, name='results'),
]
```

I’ve tried swapping out the first path variable from `’home`’ to `’’` intending Django to serve the results to the parent landing page. I also changed the name variable to `’posts’` and changed the form url hook from ‘home’ to ‘posts’ inside my template. With these changes, when the “Redact!” button is pressed, Django serves the landing page with the GET request data showing in the web address bar as intended, but then the membership card number doesn’t show below the green heading  elements as redacted.

My question for all of you is: How do I get Django to process the client’s 12 digit number and serve it on the landing page (rather than taking the user to a separate page)?

Here are the relevant lines in my **template** ([full template page source code can be found here](https://github.com/enoren5/CC_Redact_Iter3/blob/efd904f206e3783c08e277f7b955524b684c795b/templates/alls/landings.html)):

```
   <div class="card-processor">
 
   <h3>Enter your fake Chuckee Cheese Neptune membership card number!</h3>
  
   <form action="{% url 'home' %}" method="get">
    
     <div> 
       <label for="password">Enter Card Number:</label>
       <input type="text" id="password" name="ccEntry" pattern="[0-9]{12}" maxlength="12"/>
       <div class="requirements">Must be a 12 digit number and no letters. </div>
       <input type="submit" value="Redact!" class="button"/>
     </div>
 
   </form>
  
   <h1>Here is your fake Chuckee Cheese Neptune membership card number!</h1>
   <h3 style="color:lime">This was the original number that you entered:</h3>
   <div class="field">{{ number }}</div>
   <h3 style="color:lime">Here it is redacted:</h3>
   <div class="field">{{ redacted_num }}</div>    
   <a href="{% url 'posts' %}"><div class="field"><strong>Again? Click here!</strong></div></a>
  
 </div> <!--- END card-processor -->
```

Here is my app’s **views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
 
# Create your views here.
def redactors(request):
   return render(request, 'alls/landings.html')
 
def home(request):
   if 'ccEntry' in request.GET:
       number = request.GET['ccEntry']
       redacted_num = 'xxxx xxxx {}'.format(number[-4:])
       return render(request, 'alls/landings.html', {'number':number, 'redacted_num':redacted_num})
   else:
       return render(request, 'alls/landings.html')
 
def results(request):
    return render(request, 'alls/landings.html')
```

Here is the main **urls.py** in the project directory:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
 
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('', include('posts.urls')),
   path('', include('redactors.urls')),
   path('', include('counters.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In case any of you need to explore some of my other files, [here is a stratic snapshot of all my source code in its current state on GitHub](https://github.com/enoren5/CC_Redact_Iter3/tree/efd904f206e3783c08e277f7b955524b684c795b) (tagged as v0.8.0).

It's also worth noting that I'm not getting a trace back and my server is not crashing so I don't have many leads in terms of searching on Google for other developers resolving similar or related issues.

I’m running Python v3.8, Django v2.2 on Manjaro stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things to notice is the urlpatterns :

```
path('', include('posts.urls')),
```

Because this URL is on top Django will first look here.

In the **post** app you also have an urls.py that looks like the following

```
path('', views.posts, name='posts'),
```

This matches you 127.0.0.1:8000/ so this will be your homepage.

In the landings template you post to :

```
form action="{% url 'home' %}" method="get">
```

The **home** which is a different view in a different app.

If you want to first serve the Home landing page you need to do the following

**First**
Change the order in your urls.py like the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('', include('redactors.urls')), 1
   path('', include('posts.urls')), 2
   path('', include('counters.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Second**

In your **redactors** app go to your urls.py and change ’home’ to ’’

This will make sure that you always start with the home page.

The last problem you are facing is that you are missing data when you post/get to the home view.

This is because you do not give back :

```
context = {'posts':posts}
```

in the context to the render function in your home view.
So the template cannot render posts that are not available.

Comment: I first changed my project parent’s urls.py so that the ‘redactors.urls’ line is above ‘posts.urls’ line. I secondly changed `’home’` to `’’` inside my urls.py (inside redactors app). Finally, I went into `redactors.views.py` and imported the `Posts` model from my other app and passed the Posts object and included that inside my `home` function as well. Now Django renders the landing page when the web user enters their card number. So my initial question has been answered. Thank you @djangonub! Marked as solved.  I meant to follow up sooner. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Building on the progress I made with your answer here, I have a new issue on the same project. You might want to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63425939/django-fails-to-process-get-request-properly-with-a-misconfiguration-in-the-proj

:)