# Django fails to process get request properly with a misconfiguration in the project’s main urls.py

Tags: python, django

I’ve got a website I’m writing using Django which is a very basic, rudimentary CMS. For now the feature I am trying to implement involves when a web user enters their fake 12-digit chuckee cheese membership card number, Django should redact the first 8 digits and present it back to the user. All of this takes place on the main landing page with blog post text content.

Here is the `urlspatterns` variable declared inside my project’s parent urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('', include('redactors.urls')),
   path('', include('posts.urls')),   
   path('', include('counters.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

With that exact urlspatterns, [the result is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URAIh.jpg).
As you can see in that image, when the web user enters their membership card number, on the  webpage to the right, the card number (below the green heading elements) renders and is processed as intended (which is at this web address location, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?ccEntry=111111111111`. The problem is the landing page (as depicted on the left at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`), renders the template with the blog post content missing.

One solution would be to swap the order in which `path('', include('redactors.urls')),` and `path('', include('posts.urls')),` as they appear inside urlpatterns list. With that change, [the result is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZB4b.jpg). As you can see in this second image, the blog post content renders with and without the card number entered but then below the green heading element doesn’t process in the webpage to the right, it’s just blank. I’m expecting to see: ‘xxxx xxxx 1111’.

**My question is:** How do I get the `ccEntry` get request to process so that the blog post content text is rendered when the user lands on the home page *and* when the web user enters their 12-digit card number?

It's also worth noting that I'm not getting a trace back and my server is not crashing so I don't have many leads in terms of searching on Google for other developers resolving similar or related issues.

Here are the views, the template and the urls.py in play.

**[Main project urls.py](https://github.com/enoren5/CC_Redact_Iter3/blob/1b34f81d42374c58c7db88944855c6accfa604eb/CC_Redact_Iter3/urls.py)**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
 
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('', include('redactors.urls')),
   path('', include('posts.urls')),   
   path('', include('counters.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Take note of the positioning of `path('', include('redactors.urls')),` and `path('', include('posts.urls')),` When I the two positions, I get a different result but still does not achieve my goal (as described above).

**[redactors.views](https://github.com/enoren5/CC_Redact_Iter3/blob/1b34f81d42374c58c7db88944855c6accfa604eb/redactors/views.py)**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from posts.models import Posts
 
def home(request):
   if 'ccEntry' in request.GET:
       number = request.GET['ccEntry']
       redacted_num = 'xxxx xxxx {}'.format(number[-4:])
       posts = Posts.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')
       # context = {'posts':posts}
       return render(request, 'alls/landings.html', {'number':number, 'redacted_num':redacted_num, 'posts':posts, })
   else:
       return render(request, 'alls/landings.html')
```

**[posts.views](https://github.com/enoren5/CC_Redact_Iter3/blob/1b34f81d42374c58c7db88944855c6accfa604eb/posts/views.py)**:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render, get_object_or_404
from posts.models import Posts

def posts(request):
  posts = Posts.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')
  context = {'posts':posts}
  return render(request, 'alls/landings.html', context)
```

**[templates/alls.html](https://github.com/enoren5/CC_Redact_Iter3/blob/1b34f81d42374c58c7db88944855c6accfa604eb/templates/alls/landings.html)**:

```
 
   <div class="card-processor">
 
   <h3>Enter your fake Chuckee Cheese Neptune membership card number!</h3>
  
   <form action="{% url 'home' %}" method="get">
    
     <div> 
       <label for="password">Enter Card Number:</label>
       <input type="text" id="password" name="ccEntry" pattern="[0-9]{12}" maxlength="12"/>
       <div class="requirements">Must be a 12 digit number and no letters. </div>
       <input type="submit" value="Redact!" class="button"/>
     </div>
 
   </form>
  
   <h1>Here is your fake Chuckee Cheese Neptune membership card number!</h1>
   <h3 style="color:lime">This was the original number that you entered:</h3>
   <div class="field">{{ number }}</div>
   <h3 style="color:lime">Here it is redacted:</h3>
   <div class="field">{{ redacted_num }}</div>    
   <a href="{% url 'posts' %}"><div class="field"><strong>Again? Click here!</strong></div></a>
  
 </div> <!--- END card-processor -->
 
 <div class="post-content">
 {% for post in posts %}
   <h1> Blog post title: <em>{{ post.title }}</strong></em>
   <h4>Publication Date: {{ post.pub_date_preference }}</h4>
   <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" class="authors-pic" />
    
   <!-- Body text should go here :   -->
  
   <p>{{ post.body|safe }}</p>
 
 {% endfor %}
```

The above three files I think is where my problem is. But in case you people need to explore some of my other project files, [here is a static snapshot (tagged as v0.9.0)](https://github.com/enoren5/CC_Redact_Iter3/tree/1b34f81d42374c58c7db88944855c6accfa604eb) of the full source code repo on my GitHub.

Comment: It looks to me like 'ccEntry' is not in the request.GET. That is also why there is no number or redacted_num  or posts. so i would advice you to check in you home view if 'ccEntry' is available? That could be your starting point. Small  tip: instead of using function base views use Class based views it much easier to read implement and override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange: Moments ago I merged my `redactors` branch into `master`. There were two minor merge conflicts.

My `urlpatterns` list variable inside my redactor app's `urls.py` used to look like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

Basically, when I passed in 'home'` to the first path argument like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('home', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

...everything seems to run as intended. The blog post content is present with or without form input and the POST request processes as expected. Hooray!